# How does the prerender actually work?

Tags: angular

Resources on server side rendering are scarce, in fact, I couldn't find anything that clearly explains how things actually work. I've seen some repos, tried to follow the code, but didn't manage to figure out the gist of it. If I run angular normally, I know basically what happens:

1. HTML file is loaded: `<html><body><my-app>...</my-app><SCRIPTS/></body></html>`
2. Scripts are loaded...
3. Angular processes code, and replaces `<my-app>` with all the goodies inside.

For this app:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
  template: `<p *ngFor="let i of items">{{ i }}</p>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

I can see inspect html ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jm1k1pjkZ4Ib0fQjNIEV?p=preview)) and see:

```
<my-app>
  <!--template bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "1,2,3"
  }-->
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</my-app>
```

All clear so far! (:

But what happens with prerender?  If I create a file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <my-app>
    <!--template bindings={
        "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "1,2,3"
      }-->
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
  </my-app>
  <SCRIPTS/>
</body>
</html>
```

What will Angular do once scripts are loaded? Can I use this html instead of the first one? If someone understands how this process works, please share (; Any info about this stuff would be useful... Can I ***Copy outerHTML***, and make that my "prerendered page"? ...like this:

[image: Copy outerHTML]

If not, why? I'm looking for the essence of the process, an example that could be coded by hand and work...

Answer (score 17):

With server-side rendering the page gets rendered **twice**: on the server, so you can see the rendered view very early, then on the client - after the app is loaded.

- On the server side you use the [angular-universal](https://github.com/angular/universal#universal) to render any view of your app given the route URL;
- On the client your app is bootstrapped like normal - the client-rendered view is put into the app root tag and **replaces the server-rendered view**. The only magic happening on the client-side is transferring state down to the client app by [preboot.js](https://github.com/angular/universal#prebootjs) module of the universal project, which is done by recording the events triggered on the server-rendered view and then replaying them on the client-rendered view after the app is loaded. So, if you type something into the `input` box before the app is loaded, the keystrokes will be replayed by `preboot.complete()` command after the client-rendered view replaces the server-rendered one.

**Your questions:**

> What will Angular do once scripts are loaded?

Your app is bootstrapped normally, the contents of the `<my-app></my-app>` tag is replaced by the client-rendered view.

> Can I Copy outerHTML, and make that my "prerendered page"?

Yes. However, using the `angular-universal` module instead is preferable, so you can dynamically render the view behind any of your routes.

**As for the sample**, here is the [Angular 2 Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) which is a sample app that demonstrates the universal thing in action. Play with it:

- change the string `'This was rendered from the server!'` in the `dist/server/index.js` to see it's reverted back when the app is loaded. Which means that statement becomes a lie after the client view is rendered.
- enable `preboot` and postpone the `preboot.complete()` to see it in action (type something into the `input` box):

  **src/main.node.ts**

  ```
  let config: ExpressEngineConfig = {
      // ...
      preboot: { appRoot: 'app' } // your top level app component selector
  };
  ```

  **src/client.ts**

  ```
  ngApp()
  .then(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      preboot.complete();
    }, 5000);
  });
  ```

Here the simple [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cRqgaFIOcPS6sXOilaVf?p=preview) of statically served "pre-rendered" view with preboot on the client. There is a 5 seconds delay before the `app` is bootstrapped to see the preboot in action.

I'm no angular2 expert, so, please, correct me if I am wrong. I base my judgement upon reading the following resources:

- [Angular universal repo](https://github.com/angular/universal)
- [Universal design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q6g9UlmEZDXgrkY88AJZ6MUrUxcnwhBGS0EXbVlYicY)
- [Universal starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)
- [Angular universal in practice](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-universal-meet-the-internet-of-the-future-seo-friendly-single-page-web-apps/)

Comment: Thanks @Alec. I've read those resources too, or at least skimmed through, but most of the stuff there is **how to** not ***why?***. I didn't work with node server side, so that's perhaps another reason why I don't get Universal that well. Hope there will be Python port someday :P

Comment: For now I'm interested in ***so you can see the rendered view very early*** part of the story. I'll experiment with copy/paste for now and hope that when *client-rendered view is put into the app root tag and replaces the server-rendered view* things don't go terribly wrong (:

Comment: One question: for Universal we need a server, right? What can be done if we only have **static hosting**?

Comment: @Sasxa, yes a node.js server is needed. You can use the static "pre-rendered" views and still use `preboot` on the client, here the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cRqgaFIOcPS6sXOilaVf?p=preview). However, it's a real pain to keep the "pre-rendered" views and real views in sync.

Comment: @Sasxa: You ask **why** you'd want to render an Angular app on the server. The main reasons are SEO (many search engines struggle to index pages rendered on the client with JavaScript) and share-ability of deep links  from your app/website (e.g. on Twitter, Facebook). See [this Angular University article](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-universal-meet-the-internet-of-the-future-seo-friendly-single-page-web-apps/) which explains all that in detail.

Comment: @AngularFrance This question is about **how**, not why (; I wanted to know how to handle prerender when I don't have a server, for example when using firebase hosting, or when running app from USB stick...

Comment: Oops, I might have misinterpreted your earlier comment "most of the stuff there is how to not why?"

Comment: will universal render the page dynamically on the server on EACH request? Isn't that quite slow on larger apps? Is there any caching mechanism with it?

Comment: @Inna, there is an option to generate static HTML for all your routes at build time as described [here](https://universal.angular.io/overview/). This approach is less flexible but more performant.

Answer (score 2):

The process of server-side rendering Angular is mostly same as rendering it on the browser. The only difference is that the code runs on Node's JavaScript runtime as oppose to a browser hence you will miss some features that the DOM API offers.

Note that the app isn't rendered(drawn) in the server so you won't be able to access attributes such as Element.clientWidth, etc.

To summarize, the server undergoes the same process:

1. Load index.html and all embedded scripts
2. Bootstraps Angular app
3. Angular processes code, make HTTP calls, bind templates..

There are also two types of server-side rendering, and I quote from the [official site](https://universal.angular.io/overview/):

> There are two different approaches you can use for server rendering.
>   The first option is to pre-render your application which means that
>   you would use one of the Universal build tools (i.e. gulp, grunt,
>   broccoli, webpack, etc.) to generate static HTML for all your routes
>   at build time. Then you could deploy that static HTML to a CDN. The
>   advantage of this approach is that it is highly scalable and
>   performant. The disadvantage is that it is not quite as flexible as
>   the second approach.
>
> The second approach is to dynamically re-render your application on a
>   web server for each request. There are still several caching options
>   available with this approach to improve scalability and performance,
>   but you would be running your application code within the context of
>   Angular Universal for each request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `angular2-universal-preview` in order to render the app on server side:

```
    import * as express from 'express';
    import {ng2engine} from 'angular2-universal-preview';

    // Angular 2
    import {App} from './src/app';

    let app = express();

    // Express View
    app.engine('.ng2.html', ng2engine);
    app.set('views', __dirname);
    app.set('view engine', 'ng2.html');


    // static files
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));


    app.use('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', { App });
    });



    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Listen on http://localhost:3000');
    });`
```

Comment: `Universal` is just a tooling that does the job for us, doesn't help in understanding what Angular does. How would you do prerender without Universal? Or without server for that matter....